# Why doesn't Date be changed in Frappe Gannt's custom_popup_html

Tags: javascript, frappe

I will start using frappe gannt.

Even though I move task bar, progress and date not worked in custom_popup_html!

like these below.

before moving

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

after moving
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Date doesn't be changed.

code relating the issue are described.

please help about this issue!!

thank you

```js
'use strict'

function getView(view) {
  gantt.change_view_mode(view);
}

let tasks = [
  {
    id: 'Task 1',
    name: 'Redesign website',
    start: '2022-1-28',
    end: '2022-1-31',
    progress: 20,
    dependencies: ''
  },
  {
    id: 'Task 2',
    name: 'Redesign website',
    start: '2022-2-2',
    end: '2022-2-10',
    progress: 20,
    dependencies: 'Task 1'
  },
  {
    id: 'Task 3',
    name: 'Redesign website',
    start: '2022-2-12',
    end: '2022-2-20',
    progress: 20,
    dependencies: 'Task 2'
  }
]

let gantt = new Gantt("#gantt", tasks, {
  on_click: function (task) {
    console.log(task);
  },
  on_date_change: function (task, start, end) {
    console.log(task, start, end);
  },
  on_progress_change: function (task, progress) {
    console.log(task, progress);
  },
  on_view_change: function (mode) {
    console.log(mode);
  },
  custom_popup_html: function (task) {
    return `
            <div class="card" style="width: 10rem;">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h6>${task.name}</h6>
                <p>Expected to finish by ${task.end}</p>
                <p>${task.progress}% completed!</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          `;
  }
});

let btnContainer = document.getElementById("myButtonGrp");
let btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (let i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
    let current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- CSS only -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- frappe gannt  -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/frappe-gantt/0.5.0/frappe-gantt.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/frappe-gantt/0.5.0/frappe-gantt.min.js"></script>
  <!-- stylesheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='style.css'>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="shadow p-3 m-5 bg-body rounded">
    <h2 class="border-bottom mb-4">Gannt chart</h2>
    <svg id="gantt"></svg>
    <div id="myButtonGrp" class="mx-auto mt-3 btn-group" role="group">
      <button onclick="gantt.change_view_mode('Day')" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-light">Day</button>
      <button onclick="gantt.change_view_mode('Week')" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-light active">Week</button>
      <button onclick="gantt.change_view_mode('Month')" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-light">Month</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>

  <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-u1OknCvxWvY5kfmNBILK2hRnQC3Pr17a+RTT6rIHI7NnikvbZlHgTPOOmMi466C8"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: sorry , I changed it into  minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fixed version, it updates when you let go of the mouse

I added a span to your P

```
const getYYYYMMDD = date => date.toISOString().split("T")[0];

on_date_change: function(task, start, end) {
  task.start = getYYYYMMDD(start);
  task.end = getYYYYMMDD(end);
  const cardEnd = document.getElementById("fEnd");
  if (cardEnd) {
    cardEnd.textContent = task.end;
  }
},
```

```js
'use strict'

const getYYYYMMDD = date => date.toISOString().split("T")[0];

function getView(view) {
  gantt.change_view_mode(view);
}

let tasks = [{
    id: 'Task 1',
    name: 'Redesign website',
    start: '2022-1-28',
    end: '2022-1-31',
    progress: 20,
    dependencies: ''
  },
  {
    id: 'Task 2',
    name: 'Redesign website',
    start: '2022-2-2',
    end: '2022-2-10',
    progress: 20,
    dependencies: 'Task 1'
  },
  {
    id: 'Task 3',
    name: 'Redesign website',
    start: '2022-2-12',
    end: '2022-2-20',
    progress: 20,
    dependencies: 'Task 2'
  }
]

let gantt = new Gantt("#gantt", tasks, {
  on_click: function(task) {
    // console.log(task);
  },
  on_date_change: function(task, start, end) {
    task.start = getYYYYMMDD(start);
    task.end = getYYYYMMDD(end);
    const cardEnd = document.getElementById("fEnd");
    if (cardEnd) {
      cardEnd.textContent = task.end;
    }
  },
  on_progress_change: function(task, progress) {
    // console.log(task, progress);
  },
  on_view_change: function(mode) {
    // console.log(mode);
  },
  custom_popup_html: function(task) {
    return `
            <div class="card" style="width: 10rem;">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h6>${task.name}</h6>
                <p>Expected to finish by <span id="fEnd">${task.end}</span></p>
                <p>${task.progress}% completed!</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          `;
  }
});

let btnContainer = document.getElementById("myButtonGrp");
let btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (let i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
    let current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- CSS only -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- frappe gannt  -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/frappe-gantt/0.5.0/frappe-gantt.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/frappe-gantt/0.5.0/frappe-gantt.min.js"></script>
  <!-- stylesheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='style.css'>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="shadow p-3 m-5 bg-body rounded">
    <h2 class="border-bottom mb-4">Gannt chart</h2>
    <svg id="gantt"></svg>
    <div id="myButtonGrp" class="mx-auto mt-3 btn-group" role="group">
      <button onclick="gantt.change_view_mode('Day')" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-light">Day</button>
      <button onclick="gantt.change_view_mode('Week')" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-light active">Week</button>
      <button onclick="gantt.change_view_mode('Month')" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-light">Month</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>

  <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-u1OknCvxWvY5kfmNBILK2hRnQC3Pr17a+RTT6rIHI7NnikvbZlHgTPOOmMi466C8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are welcome. It was an interesting question. Please see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png)